# How to let element positioned to the browser window in Ember.js?

Tags: css, ember.js, css-position

Seems like it will only works when using `position: fixed` in application template, if I place the element under other template (let's say Index), it will positioned based on the ember-view instead of the browser window.

**So how do I make sure the element stay at the bottom of it's current view?**

Thanks.

## Solution:

Thanks to @Kalman for suggesting the conditionally render method which I put some time on it, so what I did is:

Have a named outlet under application.hbs:

```
<div class="position-fixed-bottom">
  {{outlet "placeToPutElement"}}  
</div>
```

and when in the route I need the element, render it out through `renderTemplate` with specified controller:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function()
   {
    this.render('addbtn', {into:'application', outlet: 'placeToPutElement', controller: 'controllerName'})
    //Render other content 
   }
});
```

So when we called it out, the element will stay bottom relative to the window as it is rendered in application template. (Just remember to use `position: fixed`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `{{ outlet }}` helper, your template will always be plugged-in (sorry, couldn't avoid the pun there :)) inside the parent template. So, by definition that means that you will not be able to control where it appears on the entire page.

What you probably want is to use a `render` helper instead.

See an example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dilapu/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kalman :) So even using render, we can just make the element stay at the bottom of the content, but not the window right?

Comment: Right, but the `application` template can take up the whole window, no?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm sorry that I might asking a question in the wrong way, let me edit my question.

Comment: The element will be showing throughout the app if it's placed in the `application` template, but I only need it in some of the templates. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You can conditionally render the footer in the application template - check out the following http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dilapu/2/edit

Comment: Looks like jsbin is down... I am sure they will be back soon - you can try it then :)